# Typescript & Mongoose - "this" not available in instance methods

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am currently converting my API from JS to TS. However, I'm having some difficulties with mongoose & typescript. Specifically, `this` is not available inside my instance methods.

**My code:**

```
AccountSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (candidatePassword: string) {
  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password);
  return isMatch;
};
```

**Which generates the following error as `this` refers to the function rather than the actual document:**

> Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

However, according to [Mongoose's documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods), there shouldn't be an error as `this` should refer to the actual document.

**What this actually refers to:**

```
this: {
    [name: string]: Function;
}
```

**How I defined my schema:**

```
const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IAccount>({...})
```

My approach worked just fine with JS, so I know it has something to do with TypeScript. [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) confirms that my implementation is the right way to define instance methods, so I'm quite confused why it doesn't work.

Is there a specific TS way of declaring & using instance methods in mongoose that I don't know of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'."* is pretty clearly telling you you're passing a function where a string is expected. What argument is the error on? What is the definition of the function/method you're calling? What is the definition of the argument?

Comment: May be try the shorthand.AccountSchema.methods.comparePassword = async (candidatePassword: string):  boolean => {
  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password);
  return isMatch;
};

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there shouldn't even be such an error in the first place, as "this", according to Mongoose's documentation, should refer to the actual document rather than the function

Comment: @user906573 that doesn't work as it prevents this from being bound (according to Mongoose's docs. I receive an error message that "this" is possibly undefined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated my question, should be more clear now

Comment: Is this a run time or compilation error? Also, is there a reason why the bcrypt.compare call is async / await?

Comment: @user906573 a compilation error

Comment: Ok. I have this code in vs code and it compiles ok...export const 

AccountSchema = new Schema({
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});

AccountSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword: string): boolean {
  const isMatch: boolean = this.password === candidatePassword;
  return isMatch;
};

This is the version for my npm packages:
"mongoose": "5.11.8"
"typescript": "4.1.3"

Comment: @user906573 hmmm any guesses why I receive this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227287/discussion-between-user906573-and-linus-hologram).

Comment: Cannot. Sorry. Behind corporate proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All I needed was a `this` parameter on that function. That's special in TS, and specifies the type of `this` within the function.

**Like so:**

```
async function (this: IAccount, candidatePassword: string) { ... }
```

`this` parameters are not passed explicitly, so the new parameter doesn't change how the function is called.

Comment: [`this` is a special keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) in JS. So I'd recommend **not** using the variable `this` and use some other variable.